# Conan search and download not working on virtual Artifactory repository

Tags: artifactory, conan

I am using an Artifactory system to host my Conan packages. For easier read access I have a virtual repository that contains a few local and a few remote repositories (also Conan on a different Artifactory system).

When running a conan search or download command I only get the packages from the local repos but none of the remote ones. Are these commands not supporting virtual repositories?

Strangely in the web ui I can see all packages (from local and remote repositories) in the virtual repository but the client does not seem to see it.

Artifactory version (hosting the virtual repo): 6.18.1

Artifactory version (hosting the local repos to which some of the remotes of above Artifactory are pointing to): 7.25.7

Artifactory version (hosting the local repos to which some of the remotes of above Artifactory are pointing to): Do not know version it just says JFrog Cloud

Conan client version: 1.39.0

Revisions are enabled in Conan client

What is the problem here?
Any settings to be changed in the Artifactory virtual or remote repositories?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have revisions enabled? Virtual repos only work correctly with revisions enabled.

Comment: Yes, it is. Initially I got an error message that it is not enabled. I enabled it then.

Comment: Maybe this deserves a Github issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan, it would require a bit more of information, for example, I assume that the rest of commands work? Can you ``conan install`` packages that are in the local repos and remote repos via the virtual?

Comment: No, install does not work: It cannot find the package that I can see in the web ui. Will create an issue there too. Thank you.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/9837

Comment: Searching supports virtual repositories just fine. You need to add `-r=all` or at least `-r=someremote` to the search command. Otherwise it will only search in your local cache. This is intended behaviour, as can be seem in the help (`conan search --help`).

Comment: This is known to me, thank you anyway. But this is not the issue. In my case it seems to be a problem with the remote repo configuration itself. I have a support ticket open with JFrog. Once I have a solution I will post it here as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved. The remote repo configuration in Artifactory was not correct. It was missed to use the api/conan URL format for the target repository to be cached like described here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Smart+Remote+Repositories